# How to prevent useless disk access for Web Api endpoints?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to optimize our .Net 4.0 Web Api Server (Classic 64 bits) and by tracing disk access I found out that whenever I hit a WebApi url (/collections/products/4452) IIS does several disk access. It tries to check for the existence of all these files and directories (using procmon.exe):

- /collections
- /collections/web.config
- /collections/products/
- /collections/products/web.config

The IIS server serves content from a UNC path (because it's a Web Farm) so all those useless disk access add up. Tracing reveals that this adds up to 8ms of latently.

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent those file accesses.
So far I have tried.

- Remove all handlers except the `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit`
- Remove all handlers from both `<system.web><httpHandlers>` and `<system.webServer><handlers>` and write a dummy handler that returns 'Hello World'

In both cases the file checks still occur (using procmon.exe). I'm about to try and write a low level C++ module but before we go that way I wanted to ask advice here.

I suspect that before going in my handler it does some magic in aspnet_isapi.dll, but since I can't access the code, I would hope that there is some configuration I could attempt before moving forward.